# Database logger for ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core

I have created a database logger for ASP:NET Core's logging API and I'd like to publish it on NuGet when ready. [**The GitHub repository is here**](https://github.com/SasaCetkovic/DLogger.Extensions.Logging).

The library is partly modeled after Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console and I tried to follow good practices of object-oriented design.

I am slightly concerned about some decisions I made while implementing ILogWriter interface in [SqlServerLogWriter](https://github.com/SasaCetkovic/DLogger.Extensions.Logging/blob/master/src/DLogger.Extensions.Logging/SqlServerLogWriter.cs) class AND while designing the interface for the WriteBulk method (the method is called from the LogRecordCache class).

1. Have I managed threading well enough? It works fine, but it might not look OK.
2. Should I hide exceptions or let them propagate? Logging should be redundant in production environment, so I think hiding them would be fine.
3. Is there a better way for column mapping (in SqlServerLogWriter)?
4. Any advice or contribution would be appreciated.

**LogRecordCache.cs**

```
internal static class LogRecordCache
{
    private static readonly List<LogRecord> _logs;
    private static bool _flushingInProgress = false;
    private static object _lockObject = new object();

    public static bool IsEmpty { get { return _flushingInProgress || _logs.Count == 0; } }


    static LogRecordCache()
    {
        _logs = new List<LogRecord>();
    }


    public static void Add(LogRecord log)
    {
        if (_flushingInProgress)
        {
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                _logs.Add(log);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _logs.Add(log);
        }
    }

    public static bool IsFull(int maxCount)
    {
        return !_flushingInProgress && _logs.Count >= maxCount;
    }

    public static void Flush(ILogWriter writer)
    {
        if (!_flushingInProgress)
        {
            _flushingInProgress = true;
            Task.Run(() => writer.WriteBulk(_logs, _lockObject, ref _flushingInProgress));
        }
    }
}
```

**WriteBulk() method**

```
/// <summary>
/// Writes a collection of log records to database at once
/// </summary>
/// <param name="logs">List of <see cref="LogRecord"/> objects</param>
/// <param name="lockObject">Locking object</param>
/// <param name="flushingInProgress">Indicates if writing process is still in progress; set to false at the end of this method</param>
/// <exception cref="SqlException">If opening a connection through the provided connection string was not possible</exception>
public void WriteBulk(List<LogRecord> logs, object lockObject, ref bool flushingInProgress)
{
    var lockTaken = false;
    var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, transaction))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Logging";
            foreach (var mapping in _columnMappings)
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapping.Key, mapping.Value);

            Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject, ref lockTaken);
            if (lockTaken)
            {
                using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(logs, _columnMappings.Keys.ToArray()))
                {
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = logs.Count;
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            transaction.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockTaken)
        {
            logs.Clear();
            Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
        }

        transaction.Dispose();
        connection.Close();
        flushingInProgress = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Should I hide exceptions or let them propagate? Logging should be redundant in production environment, so I think hiding them would be fine.

Both. I think this should be configurable. During setup / testing exceptions should be thrown for easier debugging (database permission issues etc.) but in production exceptions should not be thrown.

I have been using [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Troubleshooting) and at least in my use this way has been working fine.

Comment: Hmmm... I also need to take care of what happens to the cache if the ILogWriter instance is not able to flush it. I like your idea, I'll have to think about an elegant solution for all of that.